# html code is not executing the same way on server as local

Tags: html, css

I have this code in html:

```
<div id="mobile" class="container">
   /*code here*/
</div>
<div class="cont">
   /*code here*/
</div>
```

some small css code

```
#mobile{ display: none; }
@media screen and (max-width: 420px) {
    .cont{ display: none!important; }
    #mobile{ display: block!important; }
}
```

I don't know why the code is executing perfect local, but after I upload to server, is not working any more.
"working" = the media screen query is not "working"...
If I'm on mobile (screen is 360px), but the `.cont` is displayed even if is specified in the css code to not do so.
I just can't figure out why is this thing??

Comment: Is there a link where we can see this?

Comment: what is that is not working when you upload it to the server? the media query?

Comment: "is not working any more" – This is not a clear problem statement. What is different? What have you done to debug it (e.g. looking at the Network tab in your browser's developer tools to make sure that everything is loading as expected)?

Comment: Do you receive some error messages?

Comment: please read the documentation on how to make your question minimal, complete, and verifiable https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve (you need to state what the error is, and under what conditions the error occurs)

Comment: why you vote negative the question? if you don't want to help just move on!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In head need to add meta Tag :
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />`

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH! I just forget that "little argument" from the code, I don't know how... it's working now! I am very grateful!